# Compartir variables entre .py y diferentes .kv y propiedades entre .kv y .kv en kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Comunidad, tengo un problema cuando deseo compartir variables y propiedades entre diferentes archivos .kv o diferentes clases en el programa kv. Alguien tiene una idea de como podría hacerlo directamente en la programación kv?
A continuación enseño la prueba que estoy realizando

ventanas.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1024')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '738')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')


class idioma(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super(idioma, self).__init__()

class idioma_kvApp(App):
    pass

if __name__== '__main__':
    idioma_kvApp().run()
```

idioma.kv

```
#: include dos.kv


idioma:
<idioma>:

    lenguaje: lenguaje

    Label:
        text: 'uno' if lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'one' if lenguaje.text == 'English' else 'um'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.9}

    Label:
        text: 'dos' if lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'two' if lenguaje.text == 'English' else 'dois'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.8}

    Label:
        text: 'tres' if lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'tree' if lenguaje.text == 'English' else 'tres'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.7}

    Label:
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.6}
        text: 'cuatro' if lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'four' if lenguaje.text == 'English' else 'quatro'

    Label:
        text: 'cinco' if lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'five' if lenguaje.text == 'English' else 'cinco'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.5}

    Label:
        text: 'seis' if lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'six' if lenguaje.text == 'English' else 'seis'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.4}

    Label:
        text: 'siete' if lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'seven' if lenguaje.text == 'English' else 'sete'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.3}

    dos:

    Spinner:
        id: lenguaje
        text: "Espanol"
        values: ["Espanol", "English", "portugues"]
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.6}
        #on_state: root.seleccion(self.text)
```

dos.kv

```
<dos@FloatLayout>
    Label:
        text: 'ocho' if lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'eight' if lenguaje.text == 'English' else 'oito'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.2}

    Label:
        text: 'nueve' if lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'nine' if lenguaje.text == 'English' else 'nove'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.1}
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero de todo, hay que tener en cuenta que **las ids solo se comparten dentro del árbol de la regla donde es declarada**. Lo cual implica que no puedes usar la id dentro de la definición de la clase dinámica, otra cosa es en la instancia de ésta.

El problema en realidad no es que el código esté dividido en dos ficheros kv, la causa de que no funcione se debe al orden en el que es evaluado el código.

Si haces algo como:

```
<RootWidget>:
    lenguaje: lenguaje

    Label:
        id: lenguaje
        text: "Espanol"

    Dos:


<Dos@FloatLayout>
    lenguaje: self.parent.lenguaje
    Label:
        text: 'ocho' if root.lenguaje.text == 'Espanol' else 'eight'
```

Vas a obtener un error del tipo:

```
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Esto se debe a que cuando se instancia `Dos` en la regla `MainWidget` el código es evaluado antes de que la ObjectProperty `lenguaje`  sea enlazada con el widget `Label` del padre. Por lo que la property `lenguaje` de `Dos` es `None` en ese momento por lo que no tiene el atributo `text` definido.

En tu caso, la opción más simple es que en vez de compartir el widget completo simplemente compartas una `StringProperty` (variable `text` del Spinner). A diferencia de con el objeto completo, puedes dar un valor por defecto a la property dentro de la clase dinámica.

> **Nota:** Te recomiendo que cuando nombres una clase siempre empiece por mayúscula como marcan las convenciones. Esto evitará problemas y confusiones al diferenciarlas de la propiedades (siempre empiezan con minúscula).

Tu código podría quedar así:

**ventanas.py**:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.config import Config


Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1024')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '738')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')


class Idioma(FloatLayout):
    pass


class IdiomaApp(App):
    pass


if __name__== '__main__':
    IdiomaApp().run()
```

**idioma.kv:**

```
#: include dos.kv

Idioma:

<Idioma>:

    lenguaje: lenguaje.text

    Label:
        text: 'uno' if root.lenguaje == 'Espanol' else 'one' if root.lenguaje == 'English' else 'um'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.9}

    Label:
        text: 'dos' if root.lenguaje == 'Espanol' else 'two' if root.lenguaje == 'English' else 'dois'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.8}

    Label:
        text: 'tres' if root.lenguaje == 'Espanol' else 'tree' if root.lenguaje == 'English' else 'tres'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.7}

    Label:
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.6}
        text: 'cuatro' if root.lenguaje == 'Espanol' else 'four' if root.lenguaje == 'English' else 'quatro'

    Label:
        text: 'cinco' if root.lenguaje == 'Espanol' else 'five' if root.lenguaje == 'English' else 'cinco'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.5}

    Label:
        text: 'seis' if root.lenguaje == 'Espanol' else 'six' if root.lenguaje == 'English' else 'seis'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.4}

    Label:
        text: 'siete' if root.lenguaje == 'Espanol' else 'seven' if root.lenguaje == 'English' else 'sete'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.3}

    Dos:
        lenguaje: root.lenguaje

    Spinner:
        id: lenguaje
        text: "Espanol"
        values: ["Espanol", "English", "portugues"]
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.6}
        #on_state: root.seleccion(self.text)
```

**dos.kv**

```
<Dos@FloatLayout>
    lenguaje: 'Espanol'
    Label:
        text: 'ocho' if root.lenguaje == 'Espanol' else 'eight' if root.lenguaje == 'English' else 'oito'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.2}

    Label:
        text: 'nueve' if root.lenguaje == 'Espanol' else 'nine' if root.lenguaje == 'English' else 'nove'
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.1}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, no había tenido la oportunidad de responder pero la respuesta fue exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Debes entender que todo lo que haces en el .kv se usa para diseñar los complementos y crear nuevos objetos, por lo tanto basar totalmente las funciones del programa en el .kv no es una buena practica.

Deberias tratar de crear tus complementos a puro python y usar kv solo para el diseño, intenta usar las propiedades como NumericProperty.

Uso mucho *args por que no se la cantidad de parametros que pasaran por la funcion.

```
class MiObjeto(Widget):
    Altura = NumericProperty()
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MiObjeto, self).__init__(kwargs)

    def on_Altura(self, *args):
        print args



MiComplemento0 = MiObjeto()
MiComplemento1 = MiObjeto()
def Compartir_Informacion(self,*args):
    MiComplemento0.Altura = args[1] 

MiComplemento0.bind(on_Altura = Compartir_Informacion)
```